# CUDA warning "floating-point value does not fit in required integral type" - Why?

Tags: c, cuda, gpgpu

I wrote a code for multiplying 2 vectors of length "N" elements, and returning the product vector of the same length in CUDA 5.0. Here is my code
I vary the value of "N" just see how the GPU fares compared to the CPU. I am able to go up to 2000000000 elements. However when I go to 3000000000 I get the warning:

```
vecmul.cu(52): warning: floating-point value does not fit in required integral type

vecmul.cu(52): warning: floating-point value does not fit in required integral type

vecmul.cu: In function `_Z6vecmulPiS_S_':
vecmul.cu:15: warning: comparison is always false due to limited range of data type
vecmul.cu: In function `int main()':
vecmul.cu:40: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
```

And here is my code

```
 // Summing 2 Arrays

#include<stdio.h>
#include <fstream>

#define N (3000000000)

//const int threadsPerBlock = 256;

// Declare add function for Device

__global__ void vecmul(int *a,int *b,int *c)
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if (tid >= N) {return;}  // (LINE 15) 

    c[tid] = a[tid] * b[tid];
}  


int main(void)
{
// Allocate Memory  on Host
int  *a_h = new int[N];
int  *b_h = new int[N];
int  *c_h = new int[N];

// Allocate Memory on GPU

int *a_d;
int *b_d;
int *c_d;  

cudaMalloc((void**)&a_d,N*sizeof(int));
cudaMalloc((void**)&b_d,N*sizeof(int));
cudaMalloc((void**)&c_d,N*sizeof(int));

//Initialize Host Array

for (int i=0;i<N;i++)   // (LINE 40)
{
    a_h[i] = i;
    b_h[i] = (i+1);
}  

// Copy Data from Host to Device

cudaMemcpy(a_d,a_h,N*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(b_d,b_h,N*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

// Run Kernel
int blocks = int(N - 0.5)/256 + 1;   // (LINE 52)
vecmul<<<blocks,256>>>(a_d,b_d,c_d);

// Copy Data from Device to Host

cudaMemcpy(c_h,c_d,N*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

// Free Device Memory

cudaFree(a_d);
cudaFree(b_d);
cudaFree(c_d);


// Free Memory from Host

free(a_h);
free(b_h);
free(c_h);

return 0;
}
```

Is this something because of the number of blocks is not sufficient for this array size? 
Any suggestions would be welcome since I am a beginner in CUDA.
I am running this on a NVIDIA Quadro 2000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors are caused by overflowing a 32-bit signed int.  2147483648 is the max 32-bit signed int so N will always be negative, causing your boolean tests to always return true/false as specified by the warning.

The other problem is around

```
int blocks = int(N - 0.5)/256 + 1;   // (LINE 52)
```

trying to turn N into a floating point and then turn it back into an int.  The value in the floating point number is too big -- again because you've overflowed a 32-bit int.

I think if you can remove the int(), it will work since once you divide by 256, you will be small enough, but you're forcing it to int before the division, so it's too big causing the error.  It's not the assignment into blocks that's the problem, it's the explicit conversion to int.

edit: Wondering if now that we've fixed some of the computation problems with N and floating point vs int that you're seeing issues with the overflow.  For example:

```
for (int i=0;i<N;i++)   // (LINE 40)
{
    a_h[i] = i;
    b_h[i] = (i+1);
}
```

When N is over 2^31-1, this will always result in true (at least until i overflows.  This SHOULD cause this to be either an infinite loop or perhaps do 2^31-1 iterations and then exit?  The compiler says it will ALWAYS be true, which if that's the case, the loop should never end.

Also, I don't know what a size_t is in CUDA, but

```
cudaMemcpy(c_h,c_d,N*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

doing N*sizeof(int) is going way over 2^31 and even 2^32 when N=3B.

**At some point you need to ask yourself why you are trying to allocate this much space and if there is a better approach.**

Comment: +1.I modified line 52 as you suggested, and now I do not get that warning. However, I get the right result till a N of 100 million elements. When I make it a billion, I get the output vector as only zeros. It looks as if the multiplication hasn't been done at all.. Is there something simple that I am missing? Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure,since this was from a tutorial; but I think it is to obtain the smallest multiple of 256.. Correct me if I am wrong..

Comment: Uhh.. this will give you the smallest multiple of 256 guaranteed to hold N, yes.  But I'm not sure why you can't just subtract 1 and get rid of the whole int() conversion thing.

Comment: what does your code look like now?  I would just make it int blocks = (n-1)/256 + 1 .  No need for the int() stuff.

Comment: You could even try just setting blocks to the right value by hand for your N.  The math may be causing problems because of how big it is -- at least for troubleshooting initially.

Comment: I made it as int blocks = (n-1)/256 + 1, and I am still having the same problem. Then I tried to just have the number of blocks as 400000 w/o doing the blocks calculation, but I got the zeros output again...but the GPU does take time to compute. I am wondering if the computation has been performed and there is an issue in the data transfer, or the computation never happened at all...

Comment: Yeah, I don't know.  It's possible you're seeing a totally different problem now.  Perhaps before you weren't getting anything done and now you are, but something else is going wrong.  Check out my answer updates I'm about to do, as well...

Comment: @arvind you are not making any errochecking on any of your CUDA calls so you have no idea where or what is going wrong.